# Postgresql Trying to implement One-To-Many

Tags: database, postgresql

this is my first hands-on experience with Sql and I'm trying to construct One-To-Many relationship, here is the SQL code:

```
create table car (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    make VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    model VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC(19, 2) NOT NULL
);

create table person (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
    country_of_birth VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    cars_owning INT[] REFERENCES car(id)
);
```

and I get this error:

```
Key columns "cars_owning" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer[] and integer.
```

Here is the model a person can have many cars but each car have only one owner

Comment: Simply remove the “[]” after BIGINT in car table.

Comment: @Renzo sorry I wrote the model the other way around, I edited it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typically (as a good general rule of thumb) the `many` refers to the `one`. not the other way around as you have tried.

So, alter the schema as:

```
create table car (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    make VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    model VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC(19, 2) NOT NULL, 
    owner_id BIGINT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES person(id)
);

create table person (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100),
    date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
    country_of_birth VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

If you need to get the list of cars owned by a person, use this select statement

```
SELECT person.id, ARRAY_AGG(car.id) owns_car_ids
FROM person
LEFT JOIN car ON person.id = car.owner_id
GROUP BY 1
```